# How to save svg or esp file in JavaPlot

Tags: java, svg, plot, gnuplot, javaplot

I tried the code for saving png files found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806354/how-make-output-png-file-in-javaplot) and it works.
But I want to save a vector image, so I changed the terminal to: PostscriptTerminal and SVGTerminal. For the SVGTerminal the output in empty and when I use the PostscriptTerminal the code hangs at `p.plot();`

```
ImageTerminal png = new ImageTerminal();
    PostscriptTerminal eps = new PostscriptTerminal();
    SVGTerminal svg = new SVGTerminal();

    File file = new File("D:/plot.eps");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        eps.processOutput(new FileInputStream(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.print(ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.print(ex);
    }

    PlotStyle myPlotStyle = new PlotStyle();
    myPlotStyle.setStyle(Style.POINTS);
    myPlotStyle.setPointType(7); // 7 - circle
    myPlotStyle.setLineType(3); // blue color

    JavaPlot p = new JavaPlot();
    p.setPersist(false);
    p.setTerminal(eps);
    //p.setTitle(algorithm_name+" - "+problem_name, "Arial", 20);
    p.getAxis("x").setLabel("X axis", "Arial", 15);
    p.getAxis("y").setLabel("Y axis","Arial", 15);
    p.setKey(JavaPlot.Key.TOP_RIGHT);

    double[][] front = this.writeObjectivesToMatrix();
    DataSetPlot s = new DataSetPlot(front);
    s.setPlotStyle(myPlotStyle);
    s.setTitle("");
    p.addPlot(s);
    p.plot(); //code hangs here if I use PostscriptTerminal 

    try {
        //ImageIO.write(png.getImage(), "png", file); //works
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        writer.write (eps.getTextOutput());
        //Close writer
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.print(ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to save an .eps file. I only needed to add a file path in constructor and it worked.

```
PostscriptTerminal eps = new PostscriptTerminal("output.eps");

    PlotStyle myPlotStyle = new PlotStyle();
    myPlotStyle.setStyle(Style.POINTS);
    myPlotStyle.setPointType(7); // 7 - circle
    myPlotStyle.setLineType(3); // blue color

    JavaPlot p = new JavaPlot();
    p.setPersist(false);
    p.setTerminal(eps);
    p.getAxis("x").setLabel("X axis", "Arial", 15);
    p.getAxis("y").setLabel("Y axis","Arial", 15);
    p.setKey(JavaPlot.Key.TOP_RIGHT);

    double[][] front = this.writeObjectivesToMatrix();
    DataSetPlot s = new DataSetPlot(front);
    s.setPlotStyle(myPlotStyle);
    s.setTitle("");
    p.addPlot(s);
    p.plot();
```